# как присоединить многоточие ("...") к концу сокращенного предложения? Python

Tags: python

Ваша задача состоит в том, чтобы урезать предложение до длины, которая не превышает заданное количество символов.

Если данное предложение уже достаточно короткое, Вам не нужно ничего с ним делать. В случае, если его нужно урезать, отсутствующая часть должна быть обозначена присоединением многоточия ("...") к концу сокращенного предложения.

Сокращенное предложение может содержать целые слова и пробелы.
Оно не должно содержать ни усеченных слов, ни конечных пробелов.
Многоточие было учтено при расчете разрешенного количества символов, поэтому оно не засчитывается в счет заданной длины.

Входные данные:
Два аргумента:

однострочное предложение в виде строка
максимальная длина усеченного предложения в виду int
Выходные данные: Урезанное предложение с многоточием (если требуется) в виде одной строки.

Примеры:

```
cut_sentence("Hi my name is Alex", 4) == "Hi..."
cut_sentence("Hi my name is Alex", 8) == "Hi my..."
cut_sentence("Hi my name is Alex", 18) == "Hi my name is Alex"
cut_sentence("Hi my name is Alex", 20) == "Hi my name is Alex"
```

Мой код:

```
def cut_sentence(line: str, length: int) -> str:
    list_ = [str(x) for x in line.split()]
    len_word = 0
    res_word = ''
    lst2 = []
    if len(line) == 0 or length == 1:
        return '...'
    elif len(line) - (length + 3) > 0:
        for i in list_:
            if len(res_word) > length-2:
                break
            lst2.append(i)
            res_word = ' '.join(lst2)
            res_word += '...'
    else:
        return f'{line[:length]}'        
    return res_word
```

Где ошибаюсь?

Comment: А можно примеры строк, при которых данная программа будет выдавать неверный результат?

Comment: Хотя если подумать, если мы в функцию введём строку  `" programmer wants to code` и длину `1`, то по идее должно остаться `A...`, а у Вас останется `...`. Слово, состоящее из одного символа и находящееся в начале строки, тоже имеет значение

Comment: Вот пример: Your result:"Hi my name is Bartholo"
Right result:"Hi my name is..."
Fail:cut_sentence("Hi my name is Bartholomew",22)

Comment: "Сокращенное предложение может содержать целые слова и пробелы. **Оно не должно содержать ни усеченных слов, ни конечных пробелов.**" — в Вашем случае Bartholomew усекается до Bartholo, что не допускается в условии задачи

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Давайте тестировать:

```
# ваш код
...

# тест
for i in range(10):
    print(i, cut_sentence('a b c d e', i))
```

> ```
> 0                        # нет многоточия
> 1 ...                    # должно быть a...
> 2 a...
> 3 a...                   # должно быть a b...
> 4 a...                   # должно быть a b...
> 5 a...                   # должно быть a b с...
> 6 a b c                  # нет многоточия
> 7 a b c d                # нет многоточия
> 8 a b c d                # нет многоточия
> 9 a b c d e
> ```

Большая часть тестов провалилась, к сожалению.

**P.S.** Мой ответ не указывает конкретную причину ошибок. Он указывает на то что ошибок много. Возможно, вы не внимательно прочитали условие.

**P.P.S.** Регулярное выражение `r'\S\s'` совпадает с парой символов - "непробелом" и "пробелом". Между ними находится позиция по которой можно разрезать строку. Из всех таких позиций нужно выбрать самую дальнюю, но не больше заданной длины. Если таких нет, значит первый разрез слишком далеко или разрезов нет вообще. В этом случае надо вернуть только многоточие:

```
def cut_sentence(line: str, length: int) -> str:
    if len(line) <= length:
        return line
    cuts = (m.start() + 1 for m in re.finditer(r'\S\s', line))
    cut = max(filter(lambda c: c <= length, cuts), default=0)
    return f'{line[:cut]}...'
```

Comment: хороший пример показали (# тест) для проверки функции через цикл

Answer (score 4):

Как альтернативный вариант. Поскольку интересуют нас в качестве разделителя только пробелы, то можно просто искать пробел слева от нужной позиции (плюс место под искомый пробел, поэтому в срезе длина+1) и обрезать строку по нему. Если пробел не найден - обрезается вся строка. Если длины достаточно для всей строки - ничего не делаем.

```py
def cut_sentence(line: str, length: int) -> str:
    if len(line) <= length:
        return line
    return line[:max(line[:length+1].rfind(' '), 0)] + '...'

assert cut_sentence("Hi my name is Alex", 4) == "Hi..."
assert cut_sentence("Hi my name is Alex", 8) == "Hi my..."
assert cut_sentence("Hi my name is Alex", 18) == "Hi my name is Alex"
assert cut_sentence("Hi my name is Alex", 20) == "Hi my name is Alex"
```

Чем код короче, тем сложнее в нём что-то напутать.

Ну и хорошая практика - писать проверки вычислительного кода в виде `assert`-ов. Если что-то не так с функцией - вы сразу это заметите.

Comment: разобрал Ваш код на бумаге, поочередно добавляя уже в компилятор функции в срез последней строки, теперь все понятно стало, спасибо

Comment: Неверный результат если пробелов несколько подряд.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy А такое возможно по условию задачи? Мы не знаем )